# Align subscript and superscript in math mode

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, subscripts, superscripts

I'm having issues with aligning superscript with subscript in math mode. My MWE is:

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[preview,8pt,varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){CMU Bright Roman}
\usepackage[normalweight=Light,largedelims=true]{mdsymbol}
\setmathrm[ItalicFont=CMU Bright Roman, BoldFont=CMU Bright Roman,BoldItalicFont=CMU Bright Roman]{CMU Bright Roman}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
$v_{\alpha\beta}^\star$
\end{document}
```

If you take a closer look, you'll see that the star is pushed to the left slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not pushed to the left; the visual effect depends on how `\alpha` sits in its bounding box. Read in the manual of `mathspec` about the use of `"`.

With a proper math font, the subscript would probably be pushed a bit left, to take into account the shape of the letter “v”, but `mathspec` can't do that. It's just a hack, notwithstanding its cleverness.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){CMU Bright Roman}
\usepackage[normalweight=Light,largedelims=true]{mdsymbol}
\setmathrm[
  ItalicFont=CMU Bright Roman,
  BoldFont=CMU Bright Roman,
  BoldItalicFont=CMU Bright Roman
]{CMU Bright Roman}

\begin{document}

$v_{\smash{\vrule width 0.1pt height 1cm\kern-0.1pt}\alpha\beta}^\star$

$"v_{\smash{\vrule width 0.1pt height 1cm\kern-0.1pt}\alpha\beta}^\star$

\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt

\fbox{$\star$} \fbox{$\alpha$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! And what would be the way to push the star to the right, so that left point of the star is not above the letter "v"?

Comment: @MarkoP Something like `^{\,\star}` or, for finer control `^{\mkern2mu \star}`. Experiment what's best.